# How to config push notification on my own server?

Tags: java, android, sockets, push-notification

For Some reasons , GCM is not my target !

i'm trying to push notification from my server to android application , do i need use Sockets ? , when we use sockets , user is always communicating to server but i am just looking for this :
"server aware user for notifications , user request notification from server" no more data transfer or "keep-alive" connection

Answer (score 1):

If GCM is not your target, then go for TCP Sockets 
Create persistent TCP Connection from device to Server. 
Design custom protocol for notification subscription and un-subscription. And Push messages to the respective devices.

Points to Note:

1. Your application won't be able to maintain persistent TCP connection
   when device is in power saver mode.